# Any example that $f_n\rightarrow f$pointwise and $f_n'\rightarrow f'$uniformly, but not $f_n\rightarrow f$uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $C$ be an infinite connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions from $C$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Suppose
(i)$f_n'$ coverges uniformly $//$
(ii)There exists $s\in C$ such that $\{f_n(s)\}$ converges.

Then, it can be shown that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise and $f_n'\rightarrow f'$ uniformly to some function $f$.

If $C$ is bounded, then it can be also shown that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly.

However, if $C$ is unbounded, then i cannot prove that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly. Is it true or is there a counterexample to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac1nx$ on $C=\mathbb R$.